# Постоянная работа Service или Android Job

Tags: android, android-service

Работаю с сервисом.

В моём случае сервис считывает инфу с сервера и если она изменилась,то высылает уведомление.

Но проблема в том, что сервис периодически работает: если закрыть приложение через диспетчер задач,то сервис может отключиться и уведомления не приходят,пока я не зайду в приложение.

А мне нужно,чтобы сервис работал круглосуточно. И не важно закрыли приложение или нет.

MyService:

```
package com.hodite.com.shcherbuk;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.Headers;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;

public class MyService extends Service implements Constants {

    NotificationManager nm;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sp = getSharedPreferences(CHECK_SETTINGS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Создаем таймер
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
            @Override
            public void run() {
                push();
            }
        }, 1L*1000, 2L * 1000); // 600 миллисекунд до первого запуска,1800

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    public void push() {
        try {
            new asynchronousGet().run();
            Log.i("Good","good");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Eror","errorororor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void pushText(String str1,String str2){
        //String url="http://"+str2;

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent=new Intent(context,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,str2);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// оставим только самое необходимое
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
                .setContentTitle("Hodite")
                .setContentText(str1); // Текст уведомления

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        // ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify((str1+str2).hashCode(),notification);
    }


    /*---------------------КЛАСС ДЛЯ СЧИТЫВАНИЕ ТЕКСТА ИЗ ФАЙЛА-----------*/
    public class asynchronousGet {
        private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        public void run() throws Exception {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL_TEXT_TXT)
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful())
                            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                        for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                            System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                        }
                        // Log.i("Good",responseBody.string());
                        // System.out.print(responseBody.string().toString());//СЧИТАННЫЙ ТЕКСТ
                        String string=responseBody.string();
                        int count=0;
                        String[] strings=new String[2];
                        for (String str : string.split("\n")) {
                            Log.i("str",str);
                            strings[count]=str;
                            count++;
                        }
                        String s1;
                        String s2;
                            s1=sp.getString(notif_text, "notif_text");
                            Log.i("s1",s1);
                            s2=sp.getString(notif_url, "notif_url");
                            Log.i("s2",s2);
                            if(!(s1.equals(strings[0]) && s2.equals(strings[1]))){
                                /*Отправляем строки в уведомление*/
                                pushText(strings[0],strings[1]);

                                /*Сохранение переменных в SharedPreference*/
                                SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                                e.putString(notif_text, strings[0]);
                                e.putString(notif_url, strings[1]);
                                e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                            }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    /**------------------------------------------------------------------**/
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

WebActivity

```
public class WebActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Constants{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**Растянуть окно на весь экран**/
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){
            startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
        }

        refresh=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadWeb();
                refresh.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });


       // Toast.makeText(this,"Данное приложение может взымать большое количество интернет-трафика",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        loadWeb();

    }



    public void loadWeb(){


        //Intent intent=getIntent();
        url=getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_INTENT);

        web=(XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.web_xwalkview);
        web.setResourceClient(new ResourceClient(web));
        web.setUIClient(new UIClient(web));
        web.clearCache(true);
        web.load(url, null);
        //progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    }

    /**-----------------------------ПРОВЕРКА НА ЗАПУСК СЕРВИСА--------------------**/
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Выход")
                .setMessage("Ты уверен,что хочешь выйти?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        //finish();
                        //эмулируем нажатие на HOME, сворачивая приложение
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);

//в зависимости от версии оси намертво убиваем приложение
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                        {
                            finishAndRemoveTask();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            {
                                finishAffinity();
                            } else
                            {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }

                        //System.exit(0);
                        //MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
/*    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout); //Переход с затуханием
        finish();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){
            startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){
            startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){
            startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){
            startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
почитал про Android-Job и не понял как для моего случая его использовать.

русских источников по этой библиотеке нету.

кто пользовался,помогите мне для моего примера написать код с помощью Android-Job!

Comment: Переходите на JobService и Job'ы вообще, AlarmManager очень не надежная вещь. В 8м андроиде сервисы вообще превратились в тыкву. B чтоб не писать свой велосипед для разных версий андроида, сразу берите https://github.com/evernote/android-job/

Comment: Чем AlarmManager не надёжен?Ибо JobService работает только с андроида 5,0, а мне нужно с 4,0

Comment: В еверноте об этом подумали api14+: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198096/ Статья со сравнениями разных вариантов решения фоновых задач 
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/

Comment: @YuraIvanov расскажите пожалуйста принцип работы данной библиотеки. Как она работает?Она заменяет Сервис или как она может работать при выключенном приложении?

Comment: Вам просто надо почитать про job'ы в андроиде и про то как работает энергосбережение в новых апи (doze mode...). Практически все, что было написано для ранних версий, надо переделывать. Библиотека в зависимости от андроида на девайсе использует максимально подходящий вариант для выполнения фоновых задач, начиная с alarm manager'а для старых api и job'ы для новых, таким образом вам не надо думать о том, где использовать AM или JS или Firebase и проч...

Comment: @YuraIvanov так расскажите пожалуйста как пользоваться android-job в фоне. Примеров вообще нет. Я уже 5-й день мучаюсь.

Comment: На гитхабе же есть демо и доки тоже. Вот еще https://github.com/rkpattanaik/AndroidJobDemo

Answer (score 3):

Есть такой маленький трюк - сделать службу "службой переднего плана". Т.е. начать писать в строку уведомлений. Вместе с AlarmManager можно сделать "почти" неубиваемую службу (Но это не 100% вариант для Android 8+).

[Здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru#Foreground) описание работы служб.

Приведу пример с Android Developer (Здесь просят, ссылки могут стать не актуальными):

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,getText(R.string.ticker_text), System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title), getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Можно также попробовать JobSheduler. [Пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/336120/) с хабра. Код кидать не буду, много его.

Так что для Android <5 можно сделать на обычном сервисе, а для 5< на JobSheduler.

Comment: foreground не подходит. 
Я уже пробовал AlarmManager с BroadcastReceiver, но тоже работает первое только время, а потом,со временям,перестаёт работать,если не запускать приложение

Comment: @shchrbuk, а вы на чем пробовали? У меня на дев-4.4--7.0 все хорошо работало. Вы уверены, что сервис встаёт из-за урезания памяти? Переопределите методы onTrimMemory или onTaskRemoved

Comment: не могли бы вы полный пример своего кода написать?

Comment: @shcherbuk, [Вот](https://github.com/Bittuw/LogoPark/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/nikel/logoparkscanner/MainService.java), + у меня был на нем поток с подвешеным Broadcast'ом. Правда это был мой первый проект, так что многое я бы и сам переписал, не смотрите на это.

Comment: так вы через foreground делаете,а мне не нужно вечное уведомление чтобы в шторке было

Comment: @shcherbuk, его можно убрать. Создайте 2 сервис, сделайте нотификацию с тем же номером что и у первого. Удалите нотификацию и завершите сервис. Ваш первый сервис будет жить и уведомление уберётся. Но это все костыли. Как уже говорилось, сервисы больше не "круто". Другого способа я пока не знаю. Может быть job'ы и могут, но не уверен. Хотя вру, [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/336120/) говорит иначе.